# Namespace Laravel Installation

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces

I just installed Laravel under xampp in a project with name blog1. The documentation says that default namespace is App.
I create the following controller :

```
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 use App\User;
 use App\Repositories\UserRepository;
 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

 class UserController extends Controller
 {
  /**
  * The user repository implementation.
   *
   * @var UserRepository
  */
  protected $users;

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @param  UserRepository  $users
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(UserRepository $users)
{
    $this->users = $users;
}

/**
 * Show the profile for the given user.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    $user = $this->users->find($id);

    return view('user.profile', ['user' => $user]);
}
}
```

with the name testController.php under public directory.

when I http://localhost/blog1/testController.php
I get the following  Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog1\public\testController.php on line 10.
Any suggestion?
I tried to set the namespace to blog1 but now nothing happened with blog1/Http?Controller.

I reinstall Laravel through composer.

Comment: what's inside `testController.php`?

Answer (score 2):

Read about [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/), [PSR-0 (deprecated)](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) and [autoloading](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) in PHP. Error is thrown because class name (`UserController`) must be exact to the filename `testController.php` so you should name your file `UserController.php` or your class `testController`.

Also read about [Laravel's routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing) and [composer's autoloading](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading).

Answer (score 0):

The error from laravel is valid.
You're placing your file `TestController.php` under public directory, and giving the class a namespace of - `App\Http\Controllers`.

You should place your `TestController.php` inside the directory:

```
app > Http > Controllers
```

By this, your code will not throw an error again!

> See more about [Laravel Controllers & Namespacing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#controllers-and-namespaces) & [Laravel Directory Structure](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/structure#the-app-directory)

Hope this helps!